# Is gazebo a good simulator? Or are there any better ones?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ardrone2.0, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found gazebo when I was roaming around and trying to learn how ROS runs. I came across gazebo and it seemed pretty cool. I want to learn if it is a good simulator or can you suggest any other?

Can i use gazebo for drones such as AR.Drone2.0? Or do you suggest anyother simulators or programs?

P.S:Beginner

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155391/is-gazebo-a-good-simulator?-or-are-there-any-better-ones?/) by [Abdul](https://answers.ros.org/users/14906/abdul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can use gazebo for drones. Take a look:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZWTO_gREb4
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8AhNWKzv2k

You have to create model and simple controller for your model. Take a look here for some examples:
https://github.com/CrocInc/uav-croc-contest-2013

I use standalone gazebo for my tasks.

Don't know, if V-Rep is better than gazebo or not. Will try V-Rep in near future.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Charikov](https://answers.ros.org/users/14571/mike-charikov/) with karma: 123 on 2014-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1